# IDA SDK: Event when database created / opened?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

I'm writing a plugin which is available at all times (`PLUGIN_FIX` flag).
However, I also need to be notified when a database is created or opened, as if I would handle the moment when `init()` is called on plugins without the `PLUGIN_FIX` flag.

I looked into the IDA 7.0 SDK, but I only found `idb_event::closebase`, and I need the exact opposite. `idb_event::savebase` also doesn't really match.

I logged all events in the SDK ever raised by IDA (causing IDA to run slower than my grandma ☺), and only dug out `idb_event::kernel_config_loaded` which happens *around* the moment I want to catch. However, it also triggers at other times (like when simply clicking the "Open" button), so it's not a match too.

Am I missing something here? Such an event seems quite important to me, so I'm a bit surprised there's nothing "obvious" for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around a bit more, I noticed that if I handle the following two processor module (`HT_IDP`) events, I can pretty much catch the moment I wanted:

- `processor_t::event_t::ev_newfile` when a new database is being created (like from a PE file)
- `processor_t::event_t::ev_oldfile` when an existing database has been loaded (from a .idb file)